# LINQ: Why use ...Take(1).SingleOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently examining some code I'm going to maintain.

I see a few occasions of

```
.Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
```

Why would you use that instead of simply

```
.First() or .FirstOrDefault()
```

(I'm not sure whether .Take(1) would throw an exeption if the result set is empty, which imho would make the difference between the two .First... Methods?)

Comment: It depends on many factors... For example, if you would like to enable data pagination, you can call: `datacontext.Skip(currentpage*10).Take(10)`.

Comment: With the first one, an ORM will surely transform the `Take(1)` to a `TOP(1)`, and then parse the result taking the first row returned. There is no guarantee that it will translate the `First()/FirstOrDefault()` to `TOP(1)`.

Comment: Single will throw if there is more than one. Take will not thrown on an empty list the test is easy `var test = new List<int>().Take(1);`.

Comment: The two are basically equivalent. Pick one (preferably `FirstOrDefault` since it is clearer, more concise and slightly faster).

Comment: @xanatos, Im not talking First. in `.Take(1).SingleOrDefault()`, `Take` was use to be sure that single won't throw. Then I adress the last sentence in the question. op were afraid that take on empty will be an issue. When only take on null throw. The code review show a missunderstanding, op had one missunderstanding too. I'm just adress those point.

Comment: If this is on a IQueryable it might be some tweak to get the SQL code in a good looking way.

Comment: `.Take(1) would throw an exeption if the result set is empty` It won't.

Comment: I would use either `First` or `FirstOrDefault` depending on what is expected. If the collection should have elements, in other words, it would be an exceptional case that the collection would be empty, I'd use `First`. Else, if the collection could potentially be empty and that is a normal use case then I'd use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: If you truly care about an answer, you would need to tell us what LINQ provider you're using. The other thing you could do, if its sql, is see what sql it outputs and compare.

Comment: @JoePhillips I'm not yet very familiar with LINQ and wasn't aware of different providers.
There's an MSSQL db being queried, so I'd assume some LINQ to (MS)SQL provider; there's some Codesmith generated code in between, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main objection is that `.Take(1).SingleOrDefault()` defeats the purpose of `SingleOrDefault`, which is to throw an exception when the LINQ query returns more than one element.

To illustrate this, when running LINQ against a Sql Server backend `Single(OrDefault)` will translate into `SELECT TOP (2) ...` in order to determine whether there actually is one record. Preceding this by `Take(1)` will never return more than one record, so the "multiple result" exception will never occur although the code seems to require it. This code looks like a (premature) optimization by someone who's worried about returning two objects instead of one.

So the answer to your question "Why would you use that?" is: there's absolutely no reason to do it this way. There are only reasons *not* to do it.

Comment: `SELECT top (2)` isn't even a thing in mysql. Not sure why you would assume anything about the provider being used

Comment: @JoePhillips I could list all syntax alternatives here (like `LIMIT number` in MySql) but that's a bit beside the point. Any decent query provider will make sure that the semantics of Single(OrDefault) will be implemented correctly.

Comment: Why do you assume it's a decent one? I've used versions of LLBLGen that produced very horrible SQL. It's not uncommon to have inefficient implementations of that stuff. And that's assuming that it even is SQL, it might not be. It could be anything.

Comment: Then at least, *if* this is aimed at circumventing crappy SQL (or whatever) generation, I'd expect `Take(2)` here. Otherwise using `Single...` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with you and you're most likely correct but that is based on assumptions about info we don't have unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible for us to know for sure the inner implementation of whatever LINQ provider you may be using. They all vary in how they do it. Some may be more performant in cases like this whereas others may be less performant. You should get the same result either way.

It is not possible for us to read someones mind to determine why they would have done it this way in this case.

With that said, if you want to dig in deeper and it is a SQL provider, you can see what SQL it generates and compare the two cases.